# Heroku complains about the port not being bound, but I can't see the difference in my code to other solutions

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

Here is my code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({hi: 'there' });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT | 5000;
app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log('Server started...');
});
```

and my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.19.0",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

but Heroku says that "$PORT not bound in 60 seconds".

Other solutions state to do exactly as I've done. i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question - I forgot the extra bar before the 5000 port number.  It should read `process.env.PORT || 5000` - not `process.env.PORT | 5000`.

Comment: you might as well need  to enable this setting on Heroku.. `app.enable('trust proxy');` troubleshooting this piece of line is very hard